# Как получить дочерние элементы в Tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть несколько вкладок в `Tabcontrol`. Хочу получить список чекбоксов, которые прокликаны.

```
 <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="399" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="324">
    <TabItem Header="Tweaks">
        <ListBox x:Name="checkedListBoxTweaks" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableFrames}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox_TestCase" Content="{Binding Name}" 
                    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Для этого я использую следующий хелпер

```
  private static T FindVisualChild < T > (DependencyObject parent) where T: DependencyObject {
   for (int childCount = 0; childCount < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childCount++) {
    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childCount);
    if (child != null && child is T)
     return (T) child;
    else {
     T childOfChild = FindVisualChild < T > (child);
     if (childOfChild != null)
      return childOfChild;
    }
   }
   return null;
  }
```

В принципе всё работает, но получаю данные только с АКТИВНОЙ вкладки, а мне нужно со всех

```
var els = FindVisualChild<ListBox>(tabControl);
```

Comment: Почему не читать просто из VM?

Comment: А не находите вы контент с неактивной вкладки потому что его нет. TabControl создаёт контент только при необходимости — когда вкладка открыта.

Comment: @АндрейNOP тоже так думаю, но всё таки. Как обойти? и что такое VM?

Comment: Про MVVM слышали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да) , но у меня простой проект, хотелось бы без этого геморра

Comment: Ну вот без гемора с MVVM, где все достаточно просто, вы получаете гемор с контролами, который сразу так непонятно как решить

Comment: Как вариант — пишите свой контрол, который будет выглядеть как TabControl, но не будет обладать виртуализацией.